# How to store time in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Html

```
<input type="date" ng-model="bookdate" required>

 <input type="time" ng-model="booktime">
```

controller

```
$scope.insertData=function(){

 bookdate=$scope.bookdate;   
    booktime=$scope.booktime;          
 $http.post("url", {
'bookdate':bookdate,
        'booktime':booktime})
```

php

Date column datatype is date time datatype is time

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $bookdate =$data->bookdate;
    $booktime=$data->booktime; 
$newtime = date("H:i:s", strtotime($data->booktime));

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(bookdate,booktime)
VALUES ('$bookdate','$newtime')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

In database when date is submitted it storing a previous date and time value is 00:00:00

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: i need to store user entered time

Comment: You can still store it as a single entity

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (bookdatetime) VALUES ('$bookdatetime');`

Comment: I tried but it is storing current time not user entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use strtotime().

Try the below

```
$newdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data->bookdate));
$newtime = date("H:i:s", strtotime($data->booktime));
```

As long as you are getting the values to your $data->bookdate and $data->booktime this should do the trick.

Proceed to enter the new variables in your mysql database like below.

```
"INSERT INTO yourdb(booktime) VALUES('$newtime')"
```

Comment: It's working but, the correct time is not stored.For example, if input is 08:00 AM  then time stored in database is 20:30:00.

Comment: The strtotime function should pick it if you have the AM as you have mentioned. And is it exactly a 12 hour difference(12/24 hour issue)? Are you able to add a fiddle of some sort? Doesn't have to post to the server. Just some thing to see what values you are getting in your angular  post.

Comment: when I console log it I am getting correct results while storing in database time is varying i.e Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) this is console log result

Comment: Can you show me your php code relating to the DB insertion and strtotime  function part

Comment: See this. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46bf184ebefc7a716148f495c2a38ea2d43be40e

Comment: Can you show a var_dump or print_r of your $_POST array

Comment: I tried to do but am not getting.The default time zone in my PHP is America/Chicago.I tried to change it by adding     date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Asia/Calcutta')); but its not changing

Comment: Can u execute print_r($_POST) at the top of your php file receiving the post

Comment: I have executed print_r($_POST); output is blank no data.When i executed var_dump($_POST);
$data = $_POST;
exit();  output is var_dump($_POST);
array(0) { }

Comment: It's working now I have set the default time zone to Asia/Calcutta